# Jade Jquery Dialog not opening

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, pug

I'm using Jquery. Here is my jade

```
body
    div(id='dialog',title='Basic dialog')
    p test
```

and  js file

```
$(function() {
     $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
```

Dialog window not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$(function() {
     $( "#dialog" ).dialog("open");
  });
```